# print a number of lines based on entry in column 1

Tags: text-processing, files

I have been trying to answer this question for a couple of days and wasn't able to google anything useful for my problem. I am quite new to this, that might be why. I would be very grateful if there is someone out here who could point me in the right direction.

I have a simple .txt file with entries that looks like this:

```
locus_1:36
locus_1:38
locus_1:41
locus_1:50
locus_1:65
locus_1:66
locus_1:196
locus_2:9
locus_2:36
locus_2:60
locus_2:77
locus_2:89
locus_2:92
locus_2:137
locus_2:160
locus_2:172
locus_2:190
locus_2:203

locus_3:20
locus_3:60
```

I use sed to replace : with \t to get two columns.

Now I would like to create a file with only the first 3 lines for each entry in column1, i.e something like this:

```
locus_1 36
locus_1 38
locus_1 41
locus_2 9
locus_2 36
locus_2 60
locus_3 20
locus_3 60
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4):

Using AWK:

```
awk 'count[$1]++ < 3'
```

You can specify the field separator to avoid the conversion step:

```
awk -F: 'count[$1]++ < 3'
```

Answer (score 0):

**Accurately** with `awk` expression:

```
awk -F"[_:]" '$0 && a[$2]++ < 3{ print $1"_"$2, $3 > "locus_groups" }' file
```

Results:

```
$ cat locus_groups
locus_1 36
locus_1 38
locus_1 41
locus_2 9
locus_2 36
locus_2 60
locus_3 20
locus_3 60
```